# Appendix probi: "cannelam nun canianus"

Tags: vulgar-latin

Appendix probi was a book written in 3rd-4th century AD to correct people's written Latin.

It consists of lines of the form "*xxx* non *yyy*", meaning that people commonly wrote *yyy*, where *xxx* is the "correct" form.

However, a line reads:

> cannelam **nun** canianus

Why is "nun" used here?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give a link (or other reference) to where you found this? The line number might also help. I assume there are differences between editions, and some sources may even contain typos. This looks interesting, but a little more context would help.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It does look like a typo, after I've checked more sources.

Comment: I'm glad you could solve the problem yourself! +2 for that.

Answer (score 4):

It was a typo.

All of the online sources I find have been based on the book *Sprachlicher Kommentar zur vulgärlateinischen Appendix Probi*, but in the book it was correctly printed as *non* (Page 5 of [this document](https://archive.org/details/sprachlicherkomm00baeh)).

Therefore, I suspect that someone, when typing from that book, made a typographical error which is then spread everywhere.

On Page 73 of [Lingüística Romanica](https://filologiauefs.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/linguistica-romanica-rodoldo-ilari-pdf.pdf), it is also correctly printed as *non*.

Comment: FYI it could also be an OCR error https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition